# Django - Syntax highlighting with pygments

Tags: django, syntax-highlighting, pygments

I'm currently working on my blog site. One of the most important thing in appearance is multi language syntax highlighter. So I decided to use Pygments library and I wrote some code:

```
from django import template
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.formatters.html import HtmlFormatter
from pygments.lexers import get_lexer_by_name, guess_lexer
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def highlighter(content):

   soup = BeautifulSoup(unicode(content))
   codeBlocks = soup.findAll(u'code')

   for i,block in enumerate(codeBlocks):
    if block.has_attr(u'class'):
        language = block[u'class']
    else:
        language = u'text'
    try:
        lexer = get_lexer_by_name(language[0])
    except ValueError:
        try:
            lexer = guess_lexer(unicode(block))
        except ValueError:
            lexer = get_lexer_by_name(language[0])

    highlighting = highlight(unicode(block), lexer, HtmlFormatter())
    block.replaceWith(highlighting)

   return mark_safe(unicode(soup))
```

In my template i use somethink like this:

```
<p>{{ post.en_post_content|highlighter|safe|linebreaks}}</p>
```

Highlighting works well but I can't make it safe because this is what I receive:
http://i.gyazo.com/a2557c861e20a826b28cb5c261e6020f.png

I'm also worried about strange characters like "&#39"

I need advices on how to deal with it. Thanks in advance for reply.

Comment: Can you be more specific and point out what exactly you are concerned about. Further, why do you consider an apostrophe a "strange character" and why are you worried about having an apostrophe in your rendered output?